# creating dates+times every 15 minutes does not work

Tags: php, date, date-math

My php code below is supposed to create a list of following dates + times.

```
// your code goes here
$maxdays = 1;
for($daynumber=0;$daynumber<$maxdays;$daynumber++){
    $currentdayval = "+".(string)($daynumber-$maxdays)." days";
    $minutes=0;
    for($quarter=0;$quarter<24*4;$quarter++){
        $minutes += $quarter*15;
        $currentminutesval = $minutes." minutes";
        $date_sql = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($currentdayval." + ".$currentminutesval)); //current date
        echo $date_sql. "\n";
    }//for $quarter

}//for $daynr
```

But the output below shows that not every date/time follows 15 minutes after the previous date/time. Not sure where my code goes wrong(?)

```
2014-06-26 12:44:15
2014-06-26 12:59:15
2014-06-26 13:29:15
2014-06-26 14:14:15
2014-06-26 15:14:15
2014-06-26 16:29:15
2014-06-26 17:59:15
2014-06-26 19:44:15
2014-06-26 21:44:15
2014-06-26 23:59:15
2014-06-27 02:29:15
2014-06-27 05:14:15
2014-06-27 08:14:15
2014-06-27 11:29:15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your code to work, you need `$minutes` to be 0, then 15, then 30, then 45...

But because you're incrementing, you get `$minutes` set to 0, then 15... then 45 (15+30), then 90 (15+30+45), then 150 (15+30+45+60)...

Try `$minutes = $quarter * 15;` instead of `+=`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate way that is much cleaner than your current solution and avoids potential date math issues like you are having:

```
$start    = new DateTime();
$finish   = new DateTime("+{maxdays} days");
$interval = new DateInterval('PT15M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $finish);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    printf("%s\n<br>", $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/anJsKT)

It creates your start and end date/time and your interval of 15 minutes. It then use DatePeriod to loop through them and output the date and time for you. All of the date math is done by PHP for you.

Comment: +1 - I "discovered" these features quite recently, and I haven't had to use them for anything yet but they definitely look good.

Comment: They're pretty darn handy for situations exactly like this. The learning curve might be a bit high for newer users, though.

Comment: This code is much more understandable than topicstarter's

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$minutes += $quarter*15;
```

By

```
$minutes += 15;
```